# Rails Routing ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I added a new controller action and added correspondent route

```
  def students
    @students = Swimming::Student.all
    render :json => @students
  end


  namespace :swimming do 
    resources :classschedules do
        get 'students', :action => 'students', :as => :students ,:on => :collection
      end 
  end
```

but when I access this page

```
http://localhost:3000/swimming/classschedules/students
```

I got this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Swimming::ClassschedulesController#show

Couldn't find Swimming::Classschedule with id=students
```

It looks like rails tries to load another route

```
GET    /swimming/classschedules/:id(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#show
```

I am attaching all related routes

```
         swimming_classschedules GET    /swimming/classschedules(.:format)                swimming/classschedules#index
                                 POST   /swimming/classschedules(.:format)                swimming/classschedules#create
      new_swimming_classschedule GET    /swimming/classschedules/new(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#new
     edit_swimming_classschedule GET    /swimming/classschedules/:id/edit(.:format)       swimming/classschedules#edit
          swimming_classschedule GET    /swimming/classschedules/:id(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#show
                                 PUT    /swimming/classschedules/:id(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#update
                                 DELETE /swimming/classschedules/:id(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#destroy

    date_swimming_classschedules GET    /swimming/classschedules/date/:date(.:format)     swimming/classschedules#date
students_swimming_classschedules GET    /swimming/classschedules/students(.:format)       swimming/classschedules#students
editnote_swimming_classschedules POST   /swimming/classschedules/editnote/:date(.:format) swimming/classschedules#editnote
                                 GET    /swimming/classschedules(.:format)                swimming/classschedules#index
                                 POST   /swimming/classschedules(.:format)                swimming/classschedules#create
                                 GET    /swimming/classschedules/new(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#new
                                 GET    /swimming/classschedules/:id/edit(.:format)       swimming/classschedules#edit
                                 GET    /swimming/classschedules/:id(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#show
                                 PUT    /swimming/classschedules/:id(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#update
                                 DELETE /swimming/classschedules/:id(.:format)            swimming/classschedules#destroy
```

How to fix this issue?

**UPDATE** **it has been fixed**

The issue because I had two blocks of

```
  namespace :swimming do 
    resources :classschedules do

     end 

   end
```

in routes.rb

Comment: Can you add the relevant section of `rake routes` output?

Comment: Possibly an ordering issue.  Do you have a separate `resources :classschedules` earlier in the file?

Comment: are you using a get request?

Comment: Thanks all. I think I have fixed the issus with your help/hint/suggestion

Comment: Cool question! I broke my brain

Comment: Could you post your solution, @wwli?

Comment: Could you also add some more information to your question why this issue occured? @wwli

Comment: You should post your solution in an answer and then select it as the answer so that this question doesn't appear in the "unanswered" questions list.

Comment: @wwli - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> The issue because I had two blocks of
>
> ```
> namespace :swimming do 
>   resources :classschedules do
>
>   end 
> end
> ```
>
> in routes.rb

~ answer per [wwli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126032/wwli)